# Angular js if condition not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a statement where I need to assign a variable based on condition:

```
<b>{{ (varA.count > 1 ? {{'varB.status' | localizedString}} : '') }} </b>
```

where **{{varB.status | localizedString}}** filters 'varB.Status' with a localizedString specified in another place
if for example varB.Status is "Test" for the chosen localization it would return "Test"

This gives me error of

```
Syntax Error: Token 'varB.status' is unexpected, expecting [:]
```

Comment: Just do `<b>{{ (varA.count > 1 ? varB.status : '') }} </b>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have syntax error, you do not need interpolation inside interpolation and that too between incomplete expression. Expression will be evaluated as properties against scope itself, assuming varB is also on the scope.

Just do:-

```
<b>{{ (varA.count > 1 ? varB.status : '') }} </b>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/fRSPZi?p=preview)**

If you want to apply filter :-

```
<b>{{ (varA.count > 1 ? (varB.status | localizedString) : '') }} </b>
```

or even

```
<b>{{ (varA.count > 1 ? varB.status : '') | localizedString }} </b>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<b>{{ (varA.count > 1 ? varB.status : '') }} </b>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `{{` and `}}` braces allow you to inject an Angular expression inside HTML.

```
 <b>outside {{ my_expression }} outside</b>
                 ^^^^^^^^
```

In the above the text inside the `{{...}}` will be converted to an Angular expression.

```
 <b>outside {{ my_expression }} outside</b>
     ^^^^^                       ^^^^^
```

In the above the text outside the `{{...}}` will remain unchanged.

You can also use the `ngBind` directive to assign the result of an expression to the body of a DOM element.

```
<b ng-bind="mY_expression"></b>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind

To show the value of `varB.status` just write `varA.count > 1 ? varB.status : ''` like this.

```
<b>{{varA.count > 1 ? varB.status : ''}}</b>
```

<s>Alternatively, the above can be shorten to just this.</s>

```
<b>{{varA.count > 1 && varB.status}}</b>
         <!-- or -->
<b ng-bind="varA.count > 1 && varB.status"></b>
```

Or you could make the `<b>` optional.

```
<b ng-if="varA.count > 1">{{varB.status}}</b>
```

Comment: `{{varA.count > 1 && varB.status}}` you dont want to output false if condition does not match

Comment: @PSL would it write false or an empty string?

Comment: Using operation that way is confusing and generally gives desired output only when it is truthy. http://plnkr.co/edit/fRSPZi?p=preview

Comment: Last one is fine, but unwantedly creates 2 watches against one right?

Comment: @PSL true, but sometimes empty DOM elements can cause styling issues.

Comment: There is nothing you can't handle with CSS. :)